# How do I solve the "attempt to call a table value" runtime error on lua?

Tags: lua

I'm working on a lua script to convert IO Link data into MQTT. When I debugged the script, I got following runtime error on the function client:register :
Runtime error: attempt to call a table value (global 'string')

I understood that out of the 3 parameters needed, the eventname has to be in string. Coming from Java, I tried converting it directly in the function. It looks like this:

```
client:register( deviceHandle, string(IOhandleOnDisconnected) , IOhandleOnDisconnected )
```

It still does not work though.
Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Greetings.

Comment: what is `IOhandleOnDisconnected`? provide more context or we cannot help you fix it

Comment: Do you mean `tostring` instead?

Comment: `IOhandleOnDisconnected` is meant to be the function that is called if the connection to the IO Link device is interrupted. The code to the function is:
`local function IOhandleOnDisconnected()
  gTimer:stop()
  print('[IO-Link 2 MQTT] IO-Link device disconnected.')
end
client:register( deviceHandle, string(IOhandleOnDisconnected) , IOhandleOnDisconnected ) `

Answer (score 1):

`string` is Lua's standard library for string manipulation. It is a Lua table which cannot be called as you did in `string(IOhandleOnDisconnected)`